# Heuristic on Sobolev and BV functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, sobolev-spaces

Let $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^M$ be a Sobolev or BV vector field.

A heuristic that I've heard frequently is the following:

> $f$ is almost Lipschitz on a large "good" set but there is a small "bad" set where $Df$ is very large.

What theorems make this heuristic rigorous?

Comment: In some sense, this follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement applied to $Df$.

Comment: @gerw Could you add some details about this?

Comment: This brings to mind Federer Theorem 3.1.8.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I don't have access to the book these days. Could you write it down, please?

Comment: Good and bad sets says Calderon Zygmund decomposition to me

Comment: @Riku google books can give you the statement and proof of Federer 3.1.8:  https://books.google.com.mt/books?id=jld-BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=google+book+federer+geometric+measure+theory+3.1.8&source=bl&ots=DyIQ97bIMP&sig=ACfU3U0TJrZy7zGtLY08GipdF8y792b6gA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4993DjujhAhXLyKQKHYzqDJ4Q6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=google%20book%20federer%20geometric%20measure%20theory%203.1.8&f=false